# it is possible to connect apple bluetooth keyboard with ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I am had ubuntu 15.04 and I am using apple wired keyboard, but I want to change it with apple Bluetooth keyboard, it is possible to  connect it? if so,  which Bluetooth adapter do you suggest for this situation?